# Between not showing any result in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

In my program, there are range of fields and i need to get the result from the query based on range of inputs.

In the below code, there are multiple inputs and they are color, clarity, shape, cut. In the php code below i am taking range from the user and then using mysql query to find all possible result based on query.

For example, in the carat field consists of vales from 1 to 25 and if user enter 2 to 10 then the database should show all the field from 2 to 10. Same goes for other fields.

The field color consists values like D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K. Clarity consists values like FL,IF,VVS1,VVS2, VS1,VS2,SL1,SL2.

I want my query to find all the result in the given range and then display the result. My problem is that, nothing is being displayed, though the database has exact data in it.

All the fields of database are varchar except carat which is numeric.

```
<?php
$hostname_localhost ="localhost";
$database_localhost ="testdb";
$username_localhost ="root";
$password_localhost ="";
$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
or
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

 mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);

$carat1 = $_POST['carat1'];
$carat2 = $_POST['carat2'];
$clarity1 = $_POST['clarity1'];
$clarity2 = $_POST['clarity2'];
$color1 = $_POST['color1'];
$color2 = $_POST['color2'];
$cut1 = $_POST['cut1'];
$cut2 = $_POST['cut2'];
$shape1 = $_POST['shape1'];
$shape2 = $_POST['shape2'];
$stones = $_POST['stones'];


$query_search ="Select * from search1 where carats Between '$carat1' and '$carat2' and 
color Between'$color1' and  '$color2' and cut Between '$cut1' and '$cut2' and shape Between '$shape1' and  '$shape2' and stone ='$stones' ";

$query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());


    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_exec))
            $json_output[]=$row;
      print(json_encode($json_output));

    mysql_close();

//$rows = mysql_num_rows($query_exec);
//echo $rows;


 //while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_exec)) { $json_output[]=$row; } echo json_encode($json_output);
?>
```

if i change the query to then it gives result but it is not range.

```
$query_search ="Select * from search1 where carats Between '$carat1' and '$carat2' and 
color = '$color1' or color =  '$color2' and cut = '$cut1' or cut = '$cut2' and shape = '$shape1' or shape =  '$shape2' and stone ='$stones' ";
```

Comment: Please edit the query and show `$query_search` after variable substitution.

Comment: Why would you use `varchar` fields when the data is numeric? And you have an sql injection problem.

Comment: Between can be used if the column type is numeric

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: carat was just an example and it is numeric, sorry forgot to mention it, rest for other fields they all are varchar

Comment: @GordonLinoff 
I have editied the question and added more information, please look into it and then tell me, what is wrong my query

Comment: @esqew is right. `PDO` all the way (or `MySQLi`, if you are using specific functions in `MySQL`). With prepared statements, you can test the query by substituting using sample values.

Comment: You can do BETWEEN ... AND ... with varchars IF you do it correctly. For example I can get a list of all last names with 'SELECT * from mytable where last between 'fa%' and 'fz%' order by last' - does the user put a '%' in his post for color, cut, etc - if not you'll have to append it in PHP. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see is that the `carat` field is probably a number on db (since you said it's a numerical value). If it is so, in your query you should have this:

```
... where carats Between $carat1 and $carat2 ...
```

without quotes.

Try also fixing the query using parenthesis:

```
$query_search ="Select * from search1 where (carats Between '$carat1' and '$carat2') and (color Between'$color1' and  '$color2') and (cut Between '$cut1' and '$cut2') and (shape Between '$shape1' and '$shape2') and stone ='$stones' ";
```

Comment: problem is not with carats, it with other field, My friends says that there is too many "and" keywords which is causing problems but he is also not sure.

Comment: have you tried to run the query yourself in a mysql client and see what happens? Echo the query in order to see how it is exactly...

Comment: result is blank screen. but instead if i change the query to $query_search ="Select * from search1 where carats Between '$carat1' and '$carat2' and 
color = '$color1' or color =  '$color2' and cut = '$cut1' or cut = '$cut2' and shape = '$shape1' or shape =  '$shape2' and stone ='$stones' ";
 then i it gives me result but doesn't give range

Comment: Have you tried switching to between one field at the time and see where it breaks?

Comment: individually all of them returns result as expected but when combined it doesn't show any result